# open closed wb in path, file name "Quote#" & active sheet cell range "h5".value.xlsx

Tags: excel, vba

I've been looking for a while now with no success to run a macro to open a specific wb.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
'Opens Ref. Quote
Dim H As Range
Set H = Range("H4")
If H = "" Then
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ps As Workbook
Dim Path As String
Dim file_name As Range
Path = "U:\V3.5.0\QUOTES\"
file_name = "QUOTE#" & "H" & (".xlsx")
wb.Open
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code above is riddled with syntax issues. I will not explain everything, but please compare my code to yours so you can learn.

I made assumptions that you wanted to check the H4 actually has a value and that it will feed into the workbook name.

```
Dim H As Range
Set H = Range("H4")

If H.Value <> "" Then

    Dim Path As String
    Path = "U:\V3.5.0\QUOTES\"

    Dim file_name As Range
    file_name = "QUOTE#" & H.Value & ".xlsx"

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = wb.Open(path & file_name)

End If
```

Comment: updated code as follows, still get Run-time error '91':Sub RETRIEVE_QUOTE()
      'Opens Ref. Quote
    Dim H As Range
    Set H = Range("H4")

    If H.Value <> "" Then
    Dim Path As String
    Path = "U:\V3.5.0\QUOTES\"

    Dim file_name As Range
    file_name = "QUOTE#" & H.Value & ".xlsx"

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = wb.Open(Path & file_name)
    End If

Comment: make sure `Path & file_name` variable concatenation is a valid and legal file name that exists on your machine.

Answer (score 0):

Sub RETRIEVE_QUOTE()
    'Checks if Quote# is entered
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim H As Range
    Set H = Range("H4")
    If H.Value = "" Then
        MsgBox "Please Enter Quote#!"
        Exit Sub
    End If
   'Checks if PO# is entered
    Dim R As Range
    Set R = Range("H5")
    If R.Value = "" Then
        MsgBox "Please Enter PO#!"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    'Checks if DUE DATE is entered
    Dim D As Range
    Set D = Range("H6")
    If D.Value = "" Then
        MsgBox "Please Enter DUE DATE!"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    'Opens Ref. Quote
    If H.Value <> "" Then
    Dim Path As String
    Path = "U:\V3.5.0\QUOTES\"
    Dim file_name As String
    file_name = "QUOTE#" & H.Value & ".xlsx"
    Workbooks.Open filename:=(Path & file_name)
    End If

Comment: thank you for your help.After a few chnages, it works great